# CSS issues with wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Having some bizarre problems with my CSS in a custom Wordpress theme. For one, the  tag has a margin at the top, even though i specified margin-top:0 in my CSS, I checked the computed style and sure enough, margin-top is set to 0, and yet the problem persists.

Similarly I cannot center any  tags. I noticed in the Wordpress Post Editor when you center something it attaches a CSS class "aligncenter" so I created this in my CSS, but to no avail. Again, when I check the elements in the inspector, all of my CSS is present, but none of it is working correctly.

Am I missing something? Does Wordpress have some default values I'm not aware of?

I should note that with the first problem I fixed it by setting position to relative with a negative top value but obviously this is not an ideal solution.

Here is the page- http://blog.praxispr.ca/

Comment: Consider posting a link to the problem page/site.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a CSS Reset to the stylesheet.

Also, Wordpress can be a pain to Style.

I recommend checking out this link:

http://viewportindustries.com/#starkers

Comment: I tried adding a reset... did more harm than good. Thanks for the link!